# Hi guys, I just installed october cms and am trying to get it running and it threw an error related to the theme

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

The error is:

> 'throw new
> CmsException(Lang::get('cms::lang.theme.active.not_found'));

I have browsed and the answers I got aren't working yet. Please help me solve this.

Comment: did you set the active language in `config/cms.php` to a valid one ?

Answer (score 0):

Check in `/config/cms.php` - look for `'activeTheme' -> '???'`. If you do not have that theme installed it will throw that. Did you delete the default theme?

You should also be able to log into the backend `//your-site.com/backend` and set the current theme there. If not you might need to reinstall the CMS and DB.